# How react-create-app save the img inside?

Tags: reactjs, image

I created a simple game that displays flags on the page, if you click skip, the next flag is displayed(src link is changing) and so on. If I disconnect from the Internet, I noticed that some flags continue to be displayed; they are probably stored in the cache. Does React store them or the browser?

Link to site: www.country-flag-game.synkevych.info

```
<img className='flag' src={flagUrl} alt={countryName} />;
```

Answer (score 0):

Browser stores items like images, CSS, JS files, etc. in cache in order to save bandwidth and improve page load speed once user returns to site.

In case you want to hard reset cache from server (or inside your frontend app) the best way is to add some hash to file ending, like `en-US.customHash.png` or `en-US.png?randomlyGeneratedString`.

You could setup Webpack for adding hashes to files, so once your app.js file changes, hash is changed as well, so browser will know that file should be redownloaded.